# How can I locate a directory and automatically set the working directory path to it in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a "Box Sync" folder directly under my R's default root directory. I am trying to create code such that even if there are other directories in between my directory and the "Box Sync" folder, I can locate and set that as the working directory.

Comment: Good luck with the code. If any assistance is needed please reach SO

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list.dirs(recursive=T)` to find all directories in your working directory, then use `endsWith` to find those which are named `Box Sync` themselves. You can further filter these if needed and assign with `setwd`:

```
dirs <- list.dirs(recursive = T)  # List all directories in the working directory
box_dirs <- dirs[endsWith(dirs, 'Box Sync')]  # Show the ones ending with 'Box Sync'

box_dirs
    [1] "./Box Sync"
    [2] "./Library/Application Support/Box/Box Sync"                                    
    [3] "./Library/Logs/Box/Box Sync"           

setwd(box_dirs[1])
```